# How did Matt Murdock learn to fight (2015 show)?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, daredevil

I just finished the first season of the 2015 Daredevil show and, there is no explanation of how he learned to fight, sneak, and perform other acrobatic feats.

> Stick's training was incomplete (Matt was still a boy when Stick left him).

We can see him training by himself, but I don't think this would be enough. Is there an explanation of this in the comics, or another source?

Comment: In the original comic, no-one really trains him (at least to begin with). He's super-strong and agile because of his training regime and then becomes uber-everything when exposed to radioactive waste.

Comment: We can only assume that he sought out other teachers over the years. After all, Stick only taught him the basics and then left.

Comment: In [S1E10](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4125422/?ref_=ttep_ep10) (*Nelson VS Murdoch*) we see Foggy question Matt over this, and Matt says that it was **Stick** who taught him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the places that doesn't match up with the comics or previous movie incarnation.

Pre-Frank Miller, Matt Murdock was primarily a gymnast/boxer who learned to fight at Fogwell's Gym, plus training in secret by himself.

When Frank Miller took over the Daredevil comics, he revamped the character to have been trained by Stick. The training lasted much longer than it did in the show.

In the previous movie incarnation (non-MCU), no mention is made of Stick or ninja training. Instead, Matt trains with his father before his father's death, and then presumably continues on by himself.

As of now, the only information we have about the MCU Daredevil's training is specifically what we have seen in the show.