# Is Purity's fighting style inspired by real world martial arts?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

I've just finished watching season 3 of The CW version of Supergirl (not the 1984 version), and I'm very interested as to how the characters, specifically Purity, apply technique to their fights, rather than just right crosses all of the time.

I am particularly interested in the Worldkillers since they are the only real threat that the main characters face (Non was mainly a manipulator and rhea used kryptonite all the time).

I can tell that the actual style is very blunt (there is no spinning and jumping etc.), but I'm not competent enough to identify the exact real-life parallel to any specific martial art(s).

What fighting style does Purity use?

Here is an example of Purity's fighting style:

Comment: FYI there is a martial arts stackexchange. They have an identification tag, though I don't know anything about their community.

Comment: I get the feeling we're going to keep receiving this question, or variations of it, over and over without end.

Comment: I am trying to find new ways to ask/make it more interesting because no one ever answers it.

Comment: @indigochild I don't think that they would let me put this on there because there are superpowers involved.

Comment: This was asked before on this site and was closed and deleted. It was reposted to the Martial Arts SE and was closed there.

Comment: Can you please give advice on how to improve this question? I tried to use the same format as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87307/what-fighting-style-does-daredevil-netflix-use

Comment: Hand-to-hand fighting starts about 1:45 in.

Comment: If not here or on the Martial Arts Stack Exchange, what about the Movies and TV one?  They often seem to discuss questions like that there, and I don't think the involvement of superpowers is any objection there.  FuzzyBoots's answer looks good, though (although I know very little about martial arts so couldn't say whether it's correct or not).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on my experience with several martial arts from Capoeira to Aikido to some flavors of Tae Kwan Do and Karate, I don't see any distinctive real-world style here. She throws looping punches without any real bracing, the sort usually thrown in bar brawls by untrained combatants. The one major block, an outside forearm block and grab, has no particular technique to it, the same with the lazy roundhouse. The backwards guillotine choke and lifting Supergirl up so that her back strikes the raised knee is a professional wrestling maneuver, and one unlikely to be able to be pulled off without either a partner willing to jump into the movement, or the use of superhuman strength.

In short, there is no distinctive martial arts style here, with the movements coming off more as what an untrained person given superhuman strength might do.

Comment: Yep. That's not "arts", that's just lazy movie fu and not even particularly well choreographed.

Comment: Is this similar to JKD then? Bruce Lee said that his style was "no style." Furthermore, on jkdcolorado.com/post/what-is-jkd the bottom of the article says that fighting is always the same. This is the same thing Bruce Lee taught when he said "a punch is just a punch and a kick is just a kick." You were saying that Purity doesn't bother with rigid or proper form; she just punches and kicks and breaks bones. Does this fall in line with the above?

Comment: @the scarlet speedster: No. Aside from that JKD does have a very specific style (which, honestly, is fairly incomplete for fighting, possibly due to Bruce's untimely passing and the system becoming calcified there), they are still executing techniques with good form. Purity is not employing efficient technique, but instead powering her way through it. To use an analogy, you can drive in a nail by hitting it with a hammer no matter how you hit it, but if you use it properly, it requires less effort and has fewer effects, like bent nails or damage to the surface being fastened.

Comment: Ok, thanks!! This is very helpful.

Comment: P.S. Here is a reputation bonus.

Comment: JKD is an ideology in which you use whatever technique makes the most sense in a fight, and does so in the most effective way. Purity is absolutely not doing that.